# ZF2 & Doctrine ORM - How to turn off the DoctrineModule cache

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have been wondering how to switch on and off the DoctrineModule cache in my development environment.

Currently my queries are cached and stored in the data/DoctrineModule/cache folder and when bug testing this can cause constipation :)

Essentially I would like to have caching set for my production environment and switched off for my development environment and to do this obviously I need the correct settings for the configs and to have a local/global config setting to deal with this.

Here is a screenshot of where the files are stored:

[image]

The following is my test configuration file:

```
<?php
return [
    'doctrine' => [
        'connection' => [
            'orm_default' => [
                'driverClass' =>'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => [
                    'host'     => 'localhost',
                    'port'     => '3306',
                    'user'     => 'pw1',
                    'password' => 'pw1',
                    'dbname'   => 'server',
                    'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'   //To use Doctrine Entity Generator
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'eventmanager' => [
            'orm_default' => [
                'subscribers' => [
                    'Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'configuration' => [
            'orm_default' => [
                'naming_strategy' => 'UnderscoreNamingStrategy',
            ],
        ],
        'authentication' => [
            'orm_default' => [
                'object_manager' => 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager',
                'identity_class' => 'RoleBasedUser\Entity\User',
                'identity_property' => 'email',
                'credential_property' => 'password',
                'credential_callable' => function(\RoleBasedUser\Entity\User $user, $passwordGiven) {
                        $hashedPassword  = $user->getPassword();
                        $passwordService = new \RoleBasedUser\Service\PasswordService();
                        return $passwordService->verify($passwordGiven, $hashedPassword);

                    },
            ],
        ],
    ]
];
```

I am certain I need to add a config, which one though I am unsure of.

thanks!

Comment: I don't see a config flag in the docs to turn off the cache. You might need to inject a dummy or null cache adapter in order to achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this has been worked out.

In my module.config.php file I had set the doctrine driver to cache => filesystem, this I changed to array and the problem has now been resolved.

```
'doctrine'           => [
    'driver' => [
        'RBU_driver'  => [
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            //cache => 'filesystem',  <-- this will cache into the data/DoctrineModule
            'cache' => 'array', //<-- this will not cache...
            'paths' => [
                __DIR__ . '/../src/RoleBasedUser/Entity'
            ]
        ],
        'orm_default' => [
            'drivers' => [
                'RoleBasedUser\Entity' => 'RBU_driver'
            ]
        ]
    ],
],
```